# How to install webapps ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, webapps

I am a new ubuntu user using 12.04 version. I want to install webapps. However, I dont want the preview versions of webapps. I want latest versions. All the tutorials for installing webapps mention the preview. Please help me in this aspect.

Thank you

```
Update :
```

As mentioned in the comments below, I tried installing the webapps. However following error resulted :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
unity-webapps-preview : Depends: xul-ext-unity but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xul-ext-websites-integration but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This error occured on Step 3 of the link in comments :

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview
```

Can someone please tell me what is this and how to correct it ?

Thanks

Comment: you can install the version 1.9 with launchpad repo here. https://launchpad.net/~webapps/+archive/ubuntu/preview/+index?field.series_filter=quantal . But the latest version is 2.5

Comment: @DuminduMahawela . But this is also a preview version as I understand. I think full or latest version is not available for 12.04. Is that so ? (Sorry, but I ve just migrated from windows, and in windows, preview is something like alpha or beta version. )

Comment: yes latest version seems not available for 12.04. You can install Ubuntu 14.04 and run `sudo apt-get install libunity-webapps0` . It is not a preview version.

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding the `not going to be installed` packages into the main installation list as folloing:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration xul-ext-webaccounts firefox
```

Comment: xul-ext-unity : Breaks: firefox (>= 15.+) but 33.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
 xul-ext-webaccounts : Breaks: firefox (>= 14.+) but 33.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
 xul-ext-websites-integration : Breaks: firefox (>= 15.+) but 33.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.---------------------------------------This is the error now :/

Comment: I actually tried and uninstalled firefox from synaptic package manager. Then it says you need to have firefox. What kind of black magic is this ?

Comment: include firefox in the installation list.

Comment: You dont get it. If firefox is installed, it gives error in comment 1, if it is not installed, it gives error in comment 2